# How do i detect multiple images in AR?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am creating this live newspaper app with ARKit which transforms images on newspaper into videos.I am able to detect one image and play a video on it but when i try doing it on two images and play a corresponding video on that images  i get an error like 
    `Attempted to add a SKNode which already has a parent`

I tried by checking tracked images and comparing them to reference images but i think something is wrong with my logic.

This is my `ViewDidAppear()` Method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

    if  let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "NewsPaperImages", bundle: Bundle.main) {

        configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 20



    }

    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let node = SCNNode()

    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {

        if(imageAnchor.referenceImage == UIImage(named: "Image2_River")) {
            self.videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "riverBeauty.mp4")
        }

        print("Yes it is an image")
        self.videoNode.play()

        let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 360))

        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width/2, y: videoScene.size.height/2)
        videoNode.yScale = -1.0
        videoScene.addChild(videoNode)

        let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)


        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene

        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        }
    return node

}
```

it should be playing video on every detected image but instead it crashes.

Comment: Ok first of all lets see `ARImageResource`group. Then tell us if you are setting your `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` to read multiple images, that can be done by changing: `configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 10` this setting has to be declared in order to detect multiple images.

Comment: Finally please tell me when you are detecting the other images cause your code its only instantiating the VideoNode when a single image is detected, then if another image is also detected the VideoNode is not instantiated but its actually being played.

Comment: @KarloA.Lopez  Please Check  i edited the code i am tracking maximum 20 images. and can you please tell me how can i instantiate another video node when a new image is detected?

Comment: @KarloA.Lopez oh got it so i created some if statements in order to check what the name of the anchor is. and according to the detected anchor i am playing the corresponding videos by instantiating the video nodes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you finish your project?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, and from what you have said I think that you need to change your logic, to create a Video Node using the `name` property of your `ARReferenceImage` instead.

When you create an `ARReferenceImage` either statically (within the `ARResourceBundle`) or dynamically you can assign it a name e.g:

[image]

Then you can use the names to add logic to assign a different video to each `referenceImage` detected.

And in order to keep your code `DRY` you could create a reusable function to create your video node.

As such a simple example might look something like so:

```
  //-------------------------
  //MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
  //-------------------------

  extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

      //1. Check We Have Detected An ARImageAnchor
      guard let validAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

      //2. Create A Video Player Node For Each Detected Target
      node.addChildNode(createdVideoPlayerNodeFor(validAnchor.referenceImage))

    }


    /// Creates An SCNNode With An AVPlayer Rendered Onto An SCNPlane
    ///
    /// - Parameter target: ARReferenceImage
    /// - Returns: SCNNode
    func createdVideoPlayerNodeFor(_ target: ARReferenceImage) -> SCNNode{

      //1. Create An SCNNode To Hold Our VideoPlayer
      let videoPlayerNode = SCNNode()

      //2. Create An SCNPlane & An AVPlayer
      let videoPlayerGeometry = SCNPlane(width: target.physicalSize.width, height: target.physicalSize.height)
      var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()

      //3. If We Have A Valid Name & A Valid Video URL The Instanciate The AVPlayer
      if let targetName = target.name,
        let validURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: targetName, withExtension: "mp4", subdirectory: "/art.scnassets") {
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: validURL)
        videoPlayer.play()
      }

      //4. Assign The AVPlayer & The Geometry To The Video Player
      videoPlayerGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoPlayer
      videoPlayerNode.geometry = videoPlayerGeometry

      //5. Rotate It
      videoPlayerNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

      return videoPlayerNode

    }

  }
```

As you can see I have opted to use an `AVPlayer` as my video content, although you can continue to use your videoScene should you so desire.

Hope it points you in the right direction...